# very long string variable?

Tags: bash, files, variable

Is there a longer type variable for building lengthy sql statements? how add new line too? I want to store the statement in a very long variable text so I can run it from sql prompt. I think it will exceed limit if I use normal variable. thanks

```
    export DATABASE_LIST="/location/dblist.cfg"
    export SQL_INSERT_TEXT=""

    while read -r USERID ORACLE_SID2
    do

    ### how do I do this if too long?? and add new line
    SQL_INSERT_TEXT="${SQL_INSERT_TEXT} longgSqlStatements; \newline"

    done < <(tac $DATABASE_LIST)

    echo ${SQL_INSERT_TEXT}


    export sqllog = "/location/sqllog.log"
    $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S accnt_name@db_name << EOF >${sqllog}
    ${SQL_INSERT_TEXT}
    EOF
```

Comment: You don't seem to use `USERID` nor `ORACLE_SID2` in your loop.  Are these variables needed at all? Why don't you just pipe the output of `tac` directly into `sqlplus` (possibly with an `awk` preprocessing stage in-between)?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not sure how I will awk it because I need loop to generate sql, also USERID and ORACLE_SID2 are used within the long sql statement

Comment: It looks like you are trying to append `longgSqlStatements; \n` to the end of a here document. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux shells generally don't have any variable types. There are just strings, and the maximum length of a string can be had by running `getconf ARG_MAX`; on my system the maximum string is about *2M* chars long.

Try using `bash`'s builtin `printf -v` to conveniently load a variable with new lines, like this:

```
printf -v s "%s\n" hello there, this works "with quotes" too\.
echo "$s"
```

Output:

```
hello
there,
this
works
with quotes
too.
```

So the syntax might be something like:

```
printf -v SQL_INSERT_TEXT '%s\n' "${SQL_INSERT_TEXT}" "longgSqlStatements;"
```

Or, depending on what's needed, perhaps:

```
printf -v SQL_INSERT_TEXT '%s\n' "${SQL_INSERT_TEXT} longgSqlStatements;"
```

Comment: thanks @agc that helps a lot. cheers